# How to set diffChangeLogFile parameter when "mvn liquibase:diff"?

Tags: maven, liquibase

I run "mvn liquibase:diff" and already configure the diffChangeLogFile, but the diffChangeLogFile file just have the head information.(like below)

***diff.changelog.xml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.2.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd"/>
```

But I run the liquibase diff in the command line way with same configuration, there are correct  information in the diffChangeLogFile file.

My ***pom.xml*** as below:

```xml
<execution>
    <id>diff</id>
    <configuration>
        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/insert_person6.xml</changeLogFile>
        <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
        <url>${liquabase.url}</url>
        <username>${liquabase.username}</username>
        <password>${liquabase.urpasswordl}</password>
        <referenceUrl>${liquabase.referenceUrl}</referenceUrl>
        <referenceUsername>${liquabase.referenceUsername}</referenceUsername>
        <referencePassword>${liquabase.referencePassword}</referencePassword>
        <diffChangeLogFile>${liquabase.diffChangeLogFile}</diffChangeLogFile>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>diff</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

Is there anyone met the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work, and given that the diffChangeLogFile is written to, the parameter must be being set correctly.

An empty file like you are seeing is usually caused by comparing two databases that are equal. Perhaps your liquibase.url and liquibase.refereneceUrl are not set correctly.

If you run liquibase:diff without the diffChangelogFile parameter it should create a diff report that includes connection information. See if that matches up with what you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
I removed the diffChangelogFile parameter, then the output show the two db is same. But in fact, the two db is different.

Comment: In the same time, it shows correct diff information by using the "liquibase diff" in command line with same configuration.
So I think the issue is not diffChangeLogFile parameter, it is just "mvn liquibase:diff" issue.

Comment: I figure out it. 
It works after I changed the "liquibase-maven-plugin" from 3.2.1 to 3.0.7. :)

Comment: Yes, that will do it. The diffChangeLog functionality was added after 3.0.7

Comment: how to add parameter diffChangelog ?